# Python - How to read subdirectories within a directory and create the same folders in another directory, if it doesn't exist?

Tags: python, directory, subdirectory

I'm trying to create Python code that checks for subdirectories within a directory and creates the same subdirectories in another directory if none exist. How can I do this? So far I can only check if there is a directory and if not I create a new one, but I can't do it for several subdirectories. I have attached the example structure below.
I made this code below, but I think it's not correct and it doesn't do it for the other subfolders automatically, it only does it for one and I have to specify its name.
Could anyone help me on this issue? Thank you.

```
 - Dir_A (1 - Check the subfolders inside this directory)
     Folder_a
     Folder_b
     Folder_c

 - Dir_B (2 - Check if they already exist in this directory
     (3 - If not exist, create the same name/subfolders of Dir_A
```

I did this code below, but I think it is not

```
import os


# Check if directory exists, if not, create it
folder = 'sub1'


def check_folder(folder):
    DIR_ORIGIM = (r'D:\RootDirectory\DirA')
    DIR_DESTININY = (r'D:\RootDirectory\DirB')
    SUBFOLDER = os.path.join(DIR_ORIGIM, folder)
    SUBFOLDER_DESTINITY = os.path.join(DIR_DESTININY, folder)
    CHECK_FOLDER = os.path.isdir(SUBFOLDER_DESTINITY)

    # If folder doesn't exist, then create it.
    if not CHECK_FOLDER:
        os.makedirs(SUBFOLDER_DESTINITY)
        print("created folder : ", SUBFOLDER_DESTINITY)

    else:
        print(SUBFOLDER, "folder already exists.")


check_folder(folder)
```

[image]

Comment: are subfolders only one level deep or several levels?
take a look at https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/create-a-directory-in-python/

Comment: Please, try to search a little. Read about [`os.listdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir) or [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk)